# all mozilla firefox extensions stopped working today and cannot be updated

Tags: firefox-extensions

After using Firefox Quantum 66 for several months with a set of extensions, I started it today and found, that all of them have been moved to the "legacy extensions" section and disabled. The version of FF has not changed (major, minor - still the same). The versions of the addons have not changed. Updates have been disabled on the hardware level (yes, this is a highly customized device, there is nothing anyone can do about it).

They refuse to update as "download failed"

They refuse to install the latest version from file as "your extension is corrupt"

All I want is my extensions back and no one tamper with them.